# Как реализовать подсветку слов в результатах поиска?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, поиск

Результаты — $result, вводимое в поле слово — $termin. Вот этот код не работает, ничего не подсвечивается:

```
$result = preg_replace('/('.$termin.')/i', "<b>$1</b>", $result);
```

Подобные примеры с регулярками из сети тоже не работают. Видимо, где-то с моей стороны ошибка при подстановке переменных. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Я ж так понимаю, что в поиске используется кириллица? Добавьте модификатор `u`.

Comment: Да, кириллица в том числе. Добавил. Не подсвечивает, но выдаёт ошибку: Notice: Array to string conversion in /site.org/views/search.php on line 12

Comment: Модификатор на это не может влиять )) Может `$termin` - это массив? Проверьте

Comment: string(10) "Tillandsia" — строка. А вот $result — точно массив — array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Array" [1]=> string(5) "Array" }

Comment: `$result` массив - вполне допустимо. Давайте не будем гадать. Покажите, что вы изменили. Что на строке 12?

Comment: `<?php $result = preg_replace('/('.$termin.')/iu', "<b>$1</b>", $result); ?>`

Comment: В том, что вы показали, нет ничего "криминального". Вот смоделированная ситуация с вашим кодм - https://ideone.com/fYLMSc - всё работает

Comment: Интересно, у меня теперь тоже работает :) Мистика просто. Скажите, а html-теги не будет кромсать и портить разметку? Может другая нужна регулярка?

Comment: Мне не очень ясна вся суть вашей задачи, но если вы хотите подсвечивать в уже сгенерированной разметке, то да - может и кромсать, и портить. Обрабатывать нужно контент между тегами, если они закрывающиеся и исключать самозакрывающиеся теги. Регулярка может быть подойдёт и эта, но для доступа к текстовым узлам, лучше использовать что-то вроде класса [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Ну, из БД выводится форматированный текст соответствующий критериям поиска и всё :) Т. е. разметка там конечно уже есть.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос лишь в том что у тебя в $result массив строк или строка? Если у тебя там массивы из MySQL то это так работать не будет, тебе цикл нужен [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php). Как говорил мой учитель, грызи документацию тык: [preg_replace();](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: А массив у меня потом и разбирается через цикл :) Просто я, старый дурак, пытался включить подсветку до цикла, вот и не работало. Но, всё равно спасибо, любая информация ценна и поглощается мною как деликатес :)

Answer (score 0):

Во-всём виновата моя невнимательность: код с подсветкой должен был находиться внутри цикла, а не вне него.